# TPage not found in the admin area although the page is there

Tags: wordpress

I tried to get help from the WordPress forum but unfortunatelly it's almost impossible to get help there.

I first noticed this problem when installing the Disqus Comment plugin. The plugin asked me to update the database in order to proceed and so I clicked on the update button. Then the "page not found" of my theme appeared on this link `https://mysiteurl.com/wp-admin/edit-comments.php?page=disqus&step=1`, so I gave up on using Disqus. But yesterday I installed Above The Fold Optimization and when I pasted the critical css and clicked save, the same thing happened but at a new url `https://mysiteurl.com/wp-admin/admin-post.php?action=abtf_criticalcss_update`

These two pages edit-comments.php and admin-post.php are inside wp-admin folder.

Something that is worth mentioning: when I put a little piece of code in the critical css section of the Above the Fold plugin, it saves normally. But when I paste the full critical css of my site (a lot of code), it doesn’t save and redirects to the page not found.

My impression is that any big task related to the database causes a redirection to the page not found of my theme.

I developed my theme from scratch and I’m not using any plugin that may be causing conflicts. My WP is hosted on Name Cheap and it uses SSL.

EDITED: The problem may be with the server but I have no idea what it could be. I installed a new copy of WP and I tested the Disqus plugin, and the same thing happened.

Comment: Hm.  Mod Security kicking in?  ModSec is a real nuisance sometimes, but helps keep your site secure.  I doubt that it's a "big task" for the database to save a large chunk of css.

Comment: WP troubleshooting 101: Does this happen with the twentyseventeen theme, and minimal plugins (only the one(s) you require to recreate the problem)?

Comment: Does the site have correct permissions set... Do you have trouble uploading images through Wordpress backend or anything? CSS shouldn’t be a massive job but I wonder is there an upload_max_filesize issue or some other setting in php.ini.

Comment: @cale_b yes, I just tried it and the same behavior happened using the WP default theme with only Disqus and Above the Fold plugins activated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the installation. I installed WP using software installer and something wrong happened in the process. Installing WP manually fix was the solution.